# How to get a reference to HtmlHelper from inside a Model class?

Tags: c#, vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a custom Html helper extension that works just fine in a razor page, eg:  `@Html.MyCustomHelper()`

I would like to call this same helper method from within a model to populate a variable with the HTML markup string but I can't figure out how to get a reference to the `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper` object that is needed as the first parameter when calling the helper method outside of a razor page (see code example below)

```
Dim Html as System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper = ' !!This is what I can't figure out!!
Dim HtmlResultString as String = MyCustomHelper(Html)
```

Note: I tagged C# and will gladly convert any C# advice/solutions to VB.

**EDIT 1:**

MyCustomHelper method:

```
    <Extension()>
    Public Function MyCustomHelper(ByVal html As HtmlHelper) As IHtmlString
         Return html.Raw("<div>Some HTML Markup</div>")
    End Function
```

When used in a razor page:

```
<div>Calling the helper inserts the HTML markup, like so</div>
@html.MyCustomHelper()
```

If you view the page source in a browser you would see:

```
<div>Calling the helper inserts the HTML markup, like so</div>
<div>Some HTML Markup</div>
```

I have greatly simplified the markup that the helper creates in the examples above.

On the actual page, when he page is loaded, the helper method is used to create some complex markup based on the current state of data and settings.  After the page is loaded, the user interacts with the page, which changes the current state, and I send an AJAX request to a Route/Controller that updates the state and sends back the updated HTML markup to insert into the DOM.  It is in the model that is handling this AJAX request that I want to call the helper method and get the HTML markup so that I can JSON encode it and send it back to the client.

Comment: It's called a hint :). You shouldn't be using view-related types in models. They make it difficult for that reason.

Comment: It may help to understand what MyCustomHelper does so we can advice on alternative approached

Comment: @bwakabats I have edited my post with additional details

Comment: Could the method/property on the model simple return "Some HTML Markup" and the razor code be "<div>@Html.Raw(Model.TheMethodOrPropertyThatReturnsTheHtml)</div>"